# How to create very realistic rain with a particle system surrounded by a fluid domain?

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation

I am working on a scene for a short film in which it is raining on a desert. One of the shots will be very close up so I want the most realistic look possible. I looked at other tutorials on how to make rain, but the splash effect is only ever simulated with a tiny white spot with dynamic paint. This would not suffice.

I tried doing fluid simulations with many fluid spheres but that didn't work that great.

I am already using Dynamic Paint from a particle system for the wetness effect and slight displacement of the desert terrain, however I am looking most for realistic splashes, which I think will really sell the effect.

Is there a way to make a fluid domain around a particle system so that it uses each droplet as a fluid and makes realistic splashes on contact with a plane at the bottom?

Thanks!